# Automatic Email Mechanism

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax

I have the bellow code on my Global.asax . It produces Email Alarms normally. My problem is that I have set to send one email every 24 hours, but the code sends every 10minutes the email. I have set :

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(CacheItemKey, "Test", null,
               DateTime.MaxValue, TimeSpan.FromHours(24)
```

but stll the application sends the email every 10minutes. I have also tried with minutes.

My Code:

```
private const string CacheItemKey = "CacheFromMe";

        public void CacheIRemovedCallback(string key,
            object value, CacheItemRemoved reason)
        {


           HitmyPage();

            // Do the service works

           DosomeWork();
        }
        private const string myPageUrl = "myurl.aspx";

        private void HitmyPage()
        {

            WebClient myclient = new WebClient();
            myclient.DownloadData(myPageUrl);
        }
        protected void Application_BegintheRequests(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // If the dummy page is hit, then it means we want to add another item

           // in cache

           if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString() == myPageUrl)
           {
              // Add the item in cache and when succesful, do the work.

                RegistermyCacheEntries();
           }
        }
        private void DosomeWork()
        {

            DoEmailStuff();
           AnotherEmailStuff();

        }
        private void DoEmailStuff()
        {

        //    Statment For Sending The Email under conditions



        }
        private void AnotherEmailStuff()
        {
        //    Another Statment for Sending Email

        }
 void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegistermyCacheEntries();

        }
        private bool RegistermyCacheEntries()
        {
           if (null != HttpContext.Current.Cache[CacheItemKey]) return false;

           HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(CacheItemKey, "Test", null,
               DateTime.MaxValue, TimeSpan.FromHours(24),
               CacheItemPriority.Normal,
                new CacheIRemovedCallback(CacheIRemovedCallback));

           return true;
        }
```

Comment: I have done what you said with the minutes. I have it to 1440 minutes and was sending every 10 minutes. I change it to 207360minutes and was still sending every 10 minutes and some times every 20minutes. No one access by mistake the dummy Url that I call from this code. The only one that has access is only the application

Comment: What is the value of `reason` parameter in the `CacheIRemovedCallback`?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(CacheItemKey, "Test", null,
              DateTime.Now.AddHours(24), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
              CacheItemPriority.Normal,
              new CacheIRemovedCallback(CacheIRemovedCallback));
```

[Syntax as in MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.add.aspx)

```
public Object Add(
    string key,
    Object value,
    CacheDependency dependencies,
    DateTime absoluteExpiration,
    TimeSpan slidingExpiration,
    CacheItemPriority priority,
    CacheItemRemovedCallback onRemoveCallback
)
```

Items are guaranteed to remain in cache for minimum 10 minutes, this is a default setting. So email sent every 10 minutes means that setting expiration time is not successful. You may change it with absoluteExpiration and slidingExpiration parameters. 
I suspect however that problem lays somewhere else. Try Insert instead of 
Add method, as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18c1wd61.aspx)

Comment: Start again to send every 10 minutes email. No it is not working

Comment: I have change it to insert, and still sends every 10minutes email. The code i used is:
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(CacheItemKey, "Test", null,
              DateTime.Now.AddHours(24), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
              CacheItemPriority.Normal,
              new CacheIRemovedCallback(CacheIRemovedCallback));